# Does installing Grub and Windows boot manager on the same EFI partition cause any problems during update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have installed Grub alongside the Windows boot manager on the same EFI partition. Will this cause any problem during updates (Windows updates, to be specific, as I have heard that Microsoft usually screws things up during an update)?

How can I modify it to prevent the problems, if there are any?

Answer (score 0):

EFI was designed to handle dual boot gracefully.   You are suppose to install all operating systems' boot loaders into the same EFI boot partition.

The only possible issues would be

- The EFI boot partition might be too small for multiple boot loaders.  However, typically the default sizes are usually plenty for two.
- Either operating system may make itself first in the boot order after an update.  This is easily fixed by changing bios settings or using the bios's EFI boot menu to select the desired OS (and possibly using OS tools to reset the boot order).

Comment: Not related to Windows & Ubuntu sharing an ESP, is that Windows updates also turn fast startup on which sets hibernation flag. That can prevent the Linux NTFS driver from seeing any NTFS partitions that were mounted by Windows. Also either Windows or Ubuntu's firmware update may reset some UEFI settings back to defaults. If you have to change any settings in UEFI, you may have to redo those. My Dell with 11th Gen Intel needed no UEFI settings changes & just worked. But many have posted they had issues & had to redo UEFI or fast startup settings.

Comment: Both windows and linux typically don't mess with UEFI settings except on first install, but if an update comes through for the bootloader in either, it is likely UEFI boot order (and possibly other things) will be reset to the OS preference.  Both also have a command to manually reset it.